# Is there register of South Australian vaccination certificates from 1870s and 1880s?

Tags: south-australia, 1880s, 1870s, medicine

Today I sighted a vaccination certificate dated 21 Apr 1880 from Gladstone in South Australia.  It belonged to an ancestor of a correspondent rather than to an ancestor of mine so I am only presenting the form itself rather than how the form was filled out or an image of it.

> ```
> Schedule A
> ```
>
> I, THE UNDERSIGNED, hereby give you notice to have the child
>   ........................................ whose Birth is now
>   Registered, number ....., book ...... Vaccinated within six months
>   from the date of its Birth pursuant to the provisions and directions
>   of "The Vaccination Act, 1872," and that in default of your so doing,
>   you will be liable to the penalties thereby imposed for neglect of
>   those provisions.
>
> You are required to produce to the Public Vaccinator, or Medical
>   Practitioner who may be applied to, the forms herewith supplied, for
>   him to fill up and sign.
>
> Dated this ............. day of ........... 187...
>
> Registrar .........................
>
> Residence .........................
>
> Name and residence of nearest Public Vaccinator
>   .............................

I have quite a few ancestors who grew up in South Australia during this period, and so I am wondering whether there is a register of all such certificates issued in South Australia that may include them?